# AWS Config / Security Hub / Organisation

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'd like to enable AWS Config on all my accounts at the organisation level using the organisation aggregator. I have also a "Security" AWS account where I want to have Security Hub as the administrator account.

I have a couple of questions regarding this.

- Do I need to enable AWS Config on all individual accounts?
- Where do set up the aggregator? On the management account or can I set it up on the "Security" account?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are using control tower , then aws config will be enabled in the region which control tower resides in.

If you are using multiple regions because control tower is not available in all regions , then you will need to enable config in those respective regions with the necessary dependencies such as the sns topic etc.

Control tower will typically deploy an aggregator in the audit account (if you're using a landingzone sort of deployment), in the respective control tower region.

If you're not using something like control tower and vanilla aws organizations.

Then you'd have to delegate the necessary account (security account) as the administrator . This needs to be done in the management account.

From there , because you are using organizations for aggregations you would not need to make invites and authorize the security account to collect config data etc.

However, if i am not mistaken , you do need to still create the authorization in the source accounts and respective regions to authorize the aggregation account and the region from which the aggregator has been created in to be able to aggregate the data. Which seems pretty counter intuitive ...